# findAll() returns empty with WHERE option

Tags: sqlite, discord.js, sequelize.js

First question on StackOverflow, long time reader first time poster or whatever people say.

I'm developing a Discord bot in my free time using Discord.js, and I'm using Sequelize to interface with a local SQLite database. I can insert data into it just fine-- however, I can't seem to delete any of the records I add. Relevant piece of code is below, which I believe to be self-contradictory:

```js
const query3 = await Towers.findAll({
  attributes: ['channelID']
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(query3)); //returns the one Tower

console.log(query3[0].channelID === channel); //returns true(!)

const query2 = await Towers.findAll({
  attributes: ['channelID'],
  where: {channelID: channel}
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(query2)); //returns empty

//DELETE FROM Towers WHERE channelID = channel;
const query = await Towers.destroy({
  where: {channelID: channel}
});
console.log(query); //returns 0, expected behavior given query2 returns empty
```

I'm attempting to delete a record from a table named Towers by passing a channel ID to it, which is expected to be unique. However, when I make any query on the database with a WHERE clause, the query returns an empty set-- even when, in this example, I sanity-checked and verified that the value I'm attempting to remove is present in the table. This occurs for both `findAll()` and `findOne()` as long as a WHERE clause is present.

(For posterity, I've double and triple checked that `channelID` was spelled correctly and with the correct capitalization in all instances.)

I'm happy to provide any more information if needed!

EDIT: As requested, the model definition...

```js
const Towers = sequelize.define('Towers', {
    serverID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    channelID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    pattern: Sequelize.STRING,
    height: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    delay: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
});
```

`channel` in the snippet in the original post is defined as `parseInt(interaction.options.getChannel('channel').id)`.

Comment: Please add a model definition and `channel` value and value type

Comment: Unsure by looking alone, but have you tried changing the the field names to not use `ID` and instead use `Id` (e.g., `channelId`).  Confirm what those fields look like in sqlite. Likewise you might want to pass in the `{underscored: true}` options in the table definition.

Comment: Also, per the docs, models should be defined with the singular form of the word.  The table will be created pluralized.  So try `define('tower', ..., {underscored: true})`

Comment: @Mike Doesn't seem to have changed anything. [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/DZSh833.png) what the log looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who happens to have the same issue I did, the answer is a doozy.

I wanted to store Discord server and channel ID's as integers, even though they're returned to you as strings when calling the API. As it turns out, **Discord snowflakes are higher than float64 precision, which JS uses**. When parsing the strings into integers to insert them into my table, the value changed from the intended number, and I was creating erroneous records.

In my case (with the actual numbers obfuscated) `interaction.options.getChannel('channel').id` returned "837512533934092340", while `parseInt(interaction.options.getChannel('channel').id` returned 837512533934092300. The number I was adding to the table was somehow 40 less!

I'm not sure if this could be fixed by using BigInt, but since it's going into a different structure anyway, I just shrugged and changed the serverId and channelId types to `Sequelize.STRING` in the model definition and removed the parseInt calls. Works like a charm now.

Good opportunity to shake my fist at JS though.

Comment: Wowza. Yes that'll do it. `837512533934092340 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER == true`.

Comment: Also, yes, it could be done with BigInt, but you would need to use a BigInt for any manipulation; e.g., `BigInt(837512533934092340)+1n==837512533934092289n`. Once it falls under the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, you could use parseInt to convert into smaller numbers; though, you wouldn't need that here. The issue with STRING is you may need to increment. In that case, you should split the string, convert to number, add, and convert back to string.